# How to show scene in landscape mode within xcode storyboard?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview, landscape-portrait, xcode-storyboard

I have storyboard project in xcode. Most scene is show in portrait orientation but I want to show one of scene in landscape mode without user rotate the device, always this scene is shown it must be in landscape. This scene has a simple viewcontroller with uiwebview object wich I open a pdf file from url. My idea is show the viewcontroller as a modal viewcontroller.

Anyone known how solve this issue?, yesterday I spend my time searching about this in Internet but I don't find out a solution.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How the scene is actually displayed is not determined by the storyboard but rather the viewcontroller. You need to create an `UIViewController` subclass and implement `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation` to return `YES` only if the interface orientation is a landscape orientation. You could do it like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

to allow both orientations or replace with

```
return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
```

to allow only one direction.

Comment: Thanks... I added the code and I changed the dimensions of uiwebview, perfect!, works fine!...